# I can't open ports on my router

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I have a tp-link td-854w router and I installed a game called League Of Legends which need some ports to be open in order to let some in-game features to work .

As example I added port 443 to port forwarding (Virtual Server) on my router settings:

[image: a screenshot]

Now when I check if the port 443 is open or not it says it's closed- I tried [Open Port Checker](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/).

I want to know what's really going on ? Why the port is still closed ?

Comment: I presume somewhere that the device will show the 'Public' IP it's using, it maybe you're behind Carrier Grade NAT which means even if you open ports, they won't be open on the internet. Check if the public IP is actually a publically routable IP (or post it here). Or you can ask your ISP if they use Carrier Grade NAT.

Answer (score 0):

Read the article
[How to open a port on the TP-Link TD-854W](https://portforward.com/tp-link/td-854w/).

The recommended settings are slightly different :

[image]

And according to
[this post](http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1944867),
the required port forwards are not only port 443 :

```
5000 - 5500 UDP - League of Legends Game Client
8393 - 8400 TCP - Patcher and Maestro
2099 TCP - PVP.Net
5223 TCP - PVP.Net
5222 TCP - PVP.Net
80 TCP - HTTP Connections
443 TCP - HTTPS Connections
8088 Spectator Mode
```

Ensure also the the IP address of your PC is static (never changes).

Comment: I know but this isn't the point , even this single port isn't open after I added the rule !

Comment: Try [ShieldsUP](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?rh1dkyd2) to scan.

Comment: Tried , result is stealth

Comment: The only difference I can see with the article is "WAN Interface" set as "Internet". Did you try it? If that doesn't help, maybe you should factory reset your browser. I also tried but failed to find a firmware update for the router.

Comment: I don't have internet in "WAN interface" I just have "pppoe1" and 2 and I'm connected on 1 so I picked it , I think I will call ISP they may be able to help

Comment: [PPPoE](https://www.flashrouters.com/blog/2012/10/16/what-is-pppoe-how-is-it-used-by-dsl-isps/) is point-to-point, more suitable for dial modems, which is not what you want. I think that this is the source of the problem and the router just doesn't apply the port rule to the Internet. Try to factory reset the router and see if it helps.